# How to get the layer from namespace?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a code with namespace like this:

namespace nameFile.**Common**.otherParameters
{

```
public interface IEntityManager : **ICommon**
{
}
```

}

And I want to get the layer name to a `property` (in C#).
How can I do that?
(see the interface inherit from the layer name + I)

Comment: Do you want to parse some sourcecode-file?

Comment: Import namefile namespace, then create instance for Layer. After that you can access its properties

Comment: I didn't understand what OP is saying specially *I want to get the layer name to a property*

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I assume `LAYER` is a class. I would suggest you reading about object oriented programming, because you may lack some basic knowledge. Edit: Namespaces can be nested [using namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces)

Comment: I want to make a property with the layer name (automatic), so I want to know how can I get it

Comment: We dont undestand what do you mean with "layer name". Please edit your question and try to explain and include some code. Usually the code is usefull to see what do you want to do.

Comment: Assuming your `ICommon` interface is declared inside the `nameFile.Common` namespace, you would just either add `using nameFile.Common;` to import the namespace or full qualify the namespace when referencing the interface. Check my "using namespaces" in my previous comment.

Comment: I want to write a code that can be use in code generation

Comment: So you want the interface name of your class? there could be more than one.  ‘this.GetType().GetInterfaces()?.FirstOrDefault()?.Name'

Comment: Right. But I know that it could be only one.

Comment: You have [project and item templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2019) and also [Code snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019)

Comment: "this.GetType().GetInterfaces()?.FirstOrDefault()?.Name", what it will give my? the class name?